# Counting vowels in text without arrays (C)

Tags: c

i have to write a program that counts all vowels in a text & gives out the percentage of every vowel for the whole text.
For whatever reason we are not allowed to use arrays, but instead should do it with getchar().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

    int current;
    int cntAll = 0;
    int cntA = 0, cntE = 0, cntI = 0, cntO = 0, cntU = 0;
    int pA = 0, pE = 0, pI = 0, pO = 0, pU = 0;

    printf("Enter Text: ");         

    while ((current = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (isspace(current)) continue;                     // check for whitespace, if whitespace continue
        else {
            switch (current) {                              // check for vowel & increase vowelcount
            case 'a':
                cntA += 1;
            case 'A':
                cntA += 1;
            case 'e':
                cntE += 1;
            case 'E':
                cntE += 1;
            case 'i':
                cntI += 1;
            case 'I':
                cntI += 1;
            case 'o':
                cntO += 1;
            case 'O':
                cntO += 1;
            case 'u':
                cntU += 1;
            case 'U':
                cntU += 1;
            }
        }

            cntAll++;
    }

    pA = (cntA / cntAll) * 100; 
    pE = (cntE / cntAll) * 100;
    pI = (cntI / cntAll) * 100;
    pO = (cntO / cntAll) * 100;
    pU = (cntU / cntAll) * 100;

    printf("\nLetters: %d\nPercentage A: %d\nPercentage E: %d\nPercentage I: %d\nPercentage O: %d\nPercentage U: %d\n",cntAll,pA,pE,pI,pO,pU);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Increasing the cntAll value works without problems, but it doesn't count the individual vowels for whatever reason.
Would appreciate any help!

Edited:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

    int current;
    int cntAll = 0;
    int cntA = 0, cntE = 0, cntI = 0, cntO = 0, cntU = 0;
    double pA = 0, pE = 0, pI = 0, pO = 0, pU = 0;

    printf("Enter Text: ");         

    while ((current = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (isspace(current)) continue;                     
        else {
            switch (current) {                              
            case 'a':case 'A':
                cntA += 1;
                break;
            case 'e':case 'E':
                cntE += 1;
                break;
            case 'i':case 'I':
                cntI += 1;
                break;
            case 'o':case 'O':
                cntO += 1;
                break;
            case 'u':case 'U':
                cntU += 1;
                break;
            }
        }

            cntAll++;
    }

    pA = 100.0 * cntA / cntAll;
    pE = 100.0 * cntE / cntAll;
    pI = 100.0 * cntI / cntAll;
    pO = 100.0 * cntO / cntAll;
    pU = 100.0 * cntU / cntAll;

    printf("\nLetters: %d\nPercentage A: %.2lf\nPercentage E: %.2lf\nPercentage I: %.2lf\nPercentage O: %.2lf\nPercentage U: %.2lf\n",cntAll,pA,pE,pI,pO,pU);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

cheers

Comment: you forgot the `break;` between the cases.

Comment: All your variables are ints, so the division will be integer division. Percentages are probably best done as floats (which you can format as ints with `printf`).

Comment: It seems like homework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to insert `break` statements between the cases.

Otherwise the program will execute all the statements below the one first entered. Actually this is a good feature. It allows you to consider multiple labels at the same time. Putting this together you get:

```
 switch (current){
 case 'a': case 'A':
    cntA += 1;
    break; // Don't follow through to the other cases.
 case 'b': case 'B': /*etc*/
```

After this, note that `(cntA / cntAll) * 100;` will evaluate the expression in parentheses in **integer arithmetic**, which will truncate it to 0 in most cases. The fix is to write it as

`100 * cntA / cntAll;`

This will still truncate to an integer. If that's not tolerable then consider using the floating point expression `100.0 * cntA / cntAll` and change your `printf` formatters accordingly. Using floating point is arguably better anyway as it obviates the potential for overflow when evaluating `100 * cntA`.

Comment: Well kinda jumped the gun there. @Bathsheba Edited the post, mind having a look over it? It still outputs only 0.00's

Comment: Your `printf` formatters are incorrect: the first one is an `int`.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help ;)

Answer (score 1):

`case` labels *falls through* to the next one below it without a `break`.

So if you read an `'a'` then *all* the cases in your `switch` will be executed.

You need something like

```
switch (current) {                              // check for vowel & increase vowelcount
case 'a':
    cntA += 1;
    break;   // <-- Note break here
...
```

Comment: Well guess im kinda dumb, forgot that totally. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First thing i notice is that you are missing `break` on every switch case. This will lead to wrong behaviour.
Second thing:

```
pA = (cntA / cntAll) * 100;
```

will calculate `cntS/cntAll` first which is `<0`. This value will be interpreted as integer so you always have `0*100` which is 0. You can rewrite it as

```
pA = (cntA * 100 ) / cntAll;
```

In that case you don't have to cast to float to get the right result. Note that for large `cntA` you may overflow.